# PHP MYSQL verify user from table and set SESSION 'username'

Tags: php, mysql, function, session

I have a forum page and want a simple login for user with usernames from a predefined mysql user table.  I use a `login.php` form file link from the forum, a get `$_POST` username, then use a `login_handle.php` file that calls a function to connect to the DB, query the users array, and try to validate that the `$_POST` username is in the queried list array.

The function is below, and then the call in `login_handle.php`  I'm getting various errors and don't know if this is at all a good approach.  I also want to start a session during the form and verification that can grab the `$_POST` username as a `$_SESSION` username and apply to subsequent forum pages.

```
    function isUsername($username){ //Test if proper Username from array.   
            $query = "SELECT username FROM users";
            $result = mysql_query($query);  
            $usernames = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $isUname = true;

            if(!in_array("username", $usernames)) {
                echo "Please enter valid user name.<br>";
                    $isUname = false;
                    } //Search for proper username in username array.

                    return $isUname;

            }
------------------handler call-----------
            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

                if(isUsername($username)==true){ // Check if username is valid.

                //$Uname = $_SESSION['username'];
                //echo "Username = " . $Uname;  
                echo '<a href="../fourm.php">go to forum</a>';
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. I suggest you rewrite/edit your question and be specific with your questions. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tnx for the welcome.  I am a newbie and did my best to present a well thought out, informational question.  I might have fallen short.

Comment: no problem, I think the better way to think here is: help us to help you. Think in people that are answering questions of stranges to help and learn.

Answer (score 0):

First, mysql is deprecated. Please use mysqli.

Second, why don't you use something like...

```
function isUsername($username){   
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username == '" . $username . "'";
```

Third: did you search and research?
These kind of question can be easily find everywhere.

Comment: Tnx for the reply and I have researched.  As a newbie it is difficult to know the how to ask the right question but i'll do my best.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it is , you need to query the specific username from $_POST , not the whole usertable.
I think requesting the number of rows ( number of apparition is a good way to get if user is in database or not , you can make it greater (>=) instead of one user condition (==)).

```
function isUsername($username){ //Test if proper Username from array.   
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users where username='$username'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);  
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $isUname = true;

        if($rows==1) {
               $isUname = true;
         }else{
            echo "Please enter valid user name.<br>";
                $isUname = false;
         }
                return $isUname;
```

### }

I used nearly the same function when I manually assigned a txt array to a variable $username to compare.  Now that I am using a user table I merely want to assign the an array of the queried users (thought mysql_fetch_assoc($result) creates the same type of assoc. array) to $username instead of the hard copied elements where it worked with before.  Is the array produced with the query different than the $usernames=array("jes34","pes22","jis44","jll124"); that prevents me from doing this?

```
    function isUsername($username){ //Test if proper Username from array.
        $usernames=array("jes34","pes22","jis44","jll124");

        $isUname = true;            
        if(!in_array($_POST["username"], $usernames)) {
            echo "Please enter valid user name.<br>";
                $isUname = false;
                } //Search for proper username in username array.

                return $isUname;
        }
```

-----function call---
if(isUsername($username)==true){ do something }

Comment: I don't think is a good idea print an "echo" inside of a function or count the rows returned, but anyway, is not a good question anyway.